# TinyMCE displaying style of ordered list

Tags: tinymce

I have a text editor with TinyMCE. An ordered list appears after some space; I want to reduce or remove that space.

How can this be done?

Comment: That's very specific did you check http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the default margin before and after `<ol>` (ordered list) elements.

You can tell TinyMCE to use a custom stylesheet.  See the [content_css](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/content_css) config option.  Point it to the same stylesheet you use for the rest of the site (if you have one).  In that stylesheet you can adjust the margins for the `ol` element.